# Mediaelement.js - Pausar/Parar todos os outros áudios/videos da mesma classe ao iniciar algum

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Estou tendo umas dores de cabeça para implementar um sistema de BGM e BGS para um site de fanfics aqui.

Estou usando o mediaelement.js pela interoperabilidade com mobile e suporte para vídeos do Youtube.

Enfim, Estou tentando implementar exatamente o que está no título: Duas "Faixas" de áudio, caracterizadas por 2 classes, sendo que ao iniciar um dos áudios ou vídeos da mesma "faixa" (classe HTML), apenas todos os outros da mesma classe devem parar.

O HTML é basicamente isso:

```
<audio class="bgm">
  <source></source>
  ...
</audio>
<video class="bgm">
  <source></source>
  ...
</video>

<video class="bgs">
  <source></source>
  ...
</video>
<audio class="bgs">
  <source></source>
  ...
</audio>
```

Enquanto que o javascript é [esse](http://pastebin.com/k6EcCyLg):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.bgm').mediaelementplayer({
        startVolume: 0.8,
        loop: false,
        features: ['playpause', 'volume'],
        alwaysShowControls: true
    });
    $('.bgm').each(function() {
        var myBGM = this;
        this.addEventListener('play', function() {
            $('.bgm').each(function() {
                if (!(this === myBGM)) {
                    this.stop();
                }
            });
        });
    });
    $('.bgs').mediaelementplayer({
        startVolume: 0.8,
        loop: true,
        features: ['playpause', 'volume'],
        alwaysShowControls: true
    });
    $('.bgs').each(function() {
        var myBGS = this;
        this.addEventListener('play', function() {
            $('.bgs').each(function() {
                if (!(this === myBGS)) {
                    this.stop();
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Obs.: Uso tanto  como , pois percebi que o youtube apenas renderiza com a tag vídeo, mas pretendo usar de fontes variadas, incluindo mp3 ogg etc, que só renderizam na tag audio. Essa questão do Youtube só renderizar em  é um bug do mediaelement ou é esperado?

Enfim, grato desde já!